# After overriding a method and casting to base type, which method will be called?

Tags: c#, inheritance

If we have this class:

```
public class a{
     public void b(){ Console.WriteLine("a"); }
}
```

And then this class:

```
public class c : a{
     public override void b(){ Console.WriteLine("c"); }
}
```

If I do this:

```
a _a = new c();
_a.b();
```

What will happen? Which method will be called? The one from base type, or the overridden one?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will happen? Which method will be called? The one from base type,
>   or the overridden one?

Firstly, you're not overriding the method `b` within class `a` from the class `c` because you haven't marked it as `virtual` (should give you a compile time error if you had tried it). However, if you mark the method within class `a` as `virtual` like below:

```
public class a
{
    public virtual void b() { Console.WriteLine("a"); }
}
```

then the result that will be printed out will be `"c"`. The reason is due to the `overriding` mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It is an error, the base class's method must be marked `virtual`, `abstract` or `override`.

In the event you add `abstract` or `virtual` to the base class's method in your example an call as you did, the overridden method will be executed -- that is the entire point of `override`.

If you don't want the base class's method to be `virtual` or `abstract`, you can use `new` on the subclass's method and it will be replaced, but not overridden.  That is, the method `b()` of the class the reference `_a` is cast to will be executed, In your example, it would be method `b` on class `a` that would be executed.

Comment: First sorry for the very late reply. You can only override a virtual method. Sure you can override overidden methods but all the overridden methods must be routed to a virtual method. As I said I rushed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can "reuse" a method.

Overriding a method requires that method to be marked abstract or virtual. When overriding a method the overridden method will be called no matter what. You can however call the base method like :

```
base.Method();
```

Overloading allows you to change the type and number of Parameters your method uses. So:

```
public int Method(int A);
```

can be overloaded as:

```
public int Method(double B);
```

Lastly you have new. This allows you to replace a Method in a derived class. If you have a method:

```
public int Method();
```

in a base class and you create a new method

```
public new int Method();
```

in a derived class your new method will be called in your derived class but the base classes method will be called if you cast your class back to the base class. Not a very clear explaination I know but I am short on time at the moment.

Hope this helps
Danny